# Dynamic, script-based animations of object creation and deletion

Tags: python, animation, scripting, objects, keyframes

New to blender. Here's my dilemma.
I am dynamically animating a protein network using a python-script using user-provided text-files.
The animation is done using key-framing for each object's actions (see below - self.frame_number and self.disjointed_frame allow the class in question to remember what frame the animation is on)

```
    def add_progressive_location_keyframe(self, frame_step):

        bpy.context.scene.frame_end += frame_step
        bpy.context.object.keyframe_insert(data_path="location", frame=self.frame_number)
        self.frame_number += frame_step
        self.disjointed_frame += frame_step
```

So far, animating reactions that merely involve the transloation of one protein from one location to another have worked fine.
However, some reactions involve two proteins forming a complex, a new protein.
In this case, I have to dynamically delete the two reactants in a certain key-frame and in that same frame create the product.
However, I cannot add a key-frame to an object I have deleted and I am unable to add a key-frame to an object that doesn't yet exist.
This results in the two reactants being deleted and the product being formed in frame 0 (the first one).

My question: How can I add key-frames to these objects in order to dynamically delete and create them in certain frames? Is there a work around I am unfamiliar with?
Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: have you experimented with hiding / unhiding instead of deleting? that can be keyframed too.

Comment: I have considered that approach, but that would require me to create all required objects (thousands) at the very beginning of the animation.

Comment: You know the position of all these atoms in advance? (ie you aren't using blender game engine to calculate reactions)

Comment: Correct. The animations are all deterministic/'predefined'. The data being fed to pyhton, and by extension blender, would allow me to place all the necessary objects in the right place and then hide/unhide them as the animation proceeds. However, can blender even handle that kind of object load and ensure a smooth animation?

Comment: I'm willing to help you do this, can you provide a small sample file or do you only have the massive file? I work on an addon called [BioBlender](https://github.com/MonZop/BioBlender) and this is a feature i was going to add anyway..

Comment: Hey man, thanks a lot for the offer :) . However, since this is part of my thesis I am expected to do it all myself (grades and such). I will give your hiding/unhiding a shot, since implementing it won't be an issue - only the overall performance may suffer. Really appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that case I propose

- preprocess the file into separate files per frame ( Alternatively create a cache dict if you have plenty of RAM, that way you avoid having to deal with writing/reading extra files :) )
- store each cloud of atom types and their coordinates something like

this:

```
 C x y z
 C x y z
 C x y z
 N x y z
 N x y z
```

- write a file reader that can take each frame's *file* and

  - on the first frame

    1. check if the object in the next step exists already, skip this step if it does.
    2. create a vertex based mesh object for each type of atom ( ie create a vertex for every atom of one type and put those in an object named something like *atom_cloud_C*, and do the same for all other atom types ). Meaning, if your file only has 3 C atoms, that your  *atom_cloud_C* only has 3 verts.
    3. on subsequent frames you read the next frame's file and overwrite the coordinates of each atom, for all atom types.

       code:

       ```
       f_v = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(verts))
       mesh.vertices.foreach_set('co', f_v)
       mesh.update()
       ```
- This produces clouds of atoms as different objects, which get updated every frame.
- Then create the spheres that represent each atom type (only need one sphere per atom type)
- Then use the dupli feature set to Verts to duplicate the various spheres that represent the atom. (this is a low memory way to display many spheres )
- instead of keyframing it all, you can attach a `bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre` to perform a function on each frame change (pre or post), examples for this can be found in the documentation.

Comment: Great! This is pretty similar to what I have so altering my code shouldn't be too bad. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: With big quantities of atoms i'd avoid key framing individual atoms, and suggest an alternative.

Comment: I will try your suggestion of "bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre" and "dupli" feature